# android maven plugin: Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration

Tags: java, android, maven, m2eclipse

I have tried to manage dependencies of my android project with maven.
I install ADT, m2e eclipse and maven android plugin. 
I have the exception in the pom.xml:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar

it seems does not accept APK
the pom.xml:

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                               http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.simpligility.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>helloflashlight</artifactId>
      <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>apk</packaging>
      <name>HelloFlashlight</name>

      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
              <artifactId>android</artifactId>
              <version>4.0.1.2</version>
              <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>

      <build>
          <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>
                    com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2
                  </groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.6.0</version>
                  <configuration>
                      <sdk>
                          <platform>18</platform>
                      </sdk>
                      <deleteConflictingFiles>
                        true
                      </deleteConflictingFiles>
                  </configuration>
                  <extensions>true</extensions>
              </plugin>
              <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                      <source>1.5</source>
                      <target>1.5</target>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>



          </plugins>
      </build>
  </project>
```

Comment: I can 't resolve problem with suggested solution :(

Answer (score 0):

This is from the m2e plugin in Eclipse, rather than maven or the android plugin that you have. I don't know anything about the android plugin, so it's possible that there are some other things needed there. The immediate problem is m2e specific, so your configuration is probably fine.

You've got 3 options, ignore, execute and delegate to a project configurator. More information on these options can be found here on the Eclipse wiki: http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered

Comment: thank you Gerard but i can't open this link.

Comment: Really? That's curious. Are you connected to a private network that may be blocking it?